# My JSON is "valid" but not working in SharePoint Column

Tags: json, sharepoint

What am I missing? The idea is that this will update a Status column on the list. I pulled from Microsoft's community post on formatting columns in SharePoint and then changed the code from the CSS class (sp-field-severity--low) to hex codes for more flexibility. I also added some additional options, because 5 wasn't enough for me. All JSON validator's state this is valid, but when saving in the column, nothing changes - no errors, nada.

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background color": "=if(@currentField == 'New', '#89CFF0', if(@currentField == 'Resolved', 
 '#A9F5BC', if(@currentField == 'Under Review', '#FFFFFF', if(@currentField == 'Need More 
  Information', '#F5DA81', if(@currentField == 'More Information Added', '#F5DA81', 
  if(@currentField == 'Waiting', '#F79F81', if(@currentField == 'Returned', '#FA5858')))))))"
  },
 "children": [
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
    "display": "inline-block",
    "padding": "0 4px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'New', 'Star', if(@currentField == 'Resolved', 
'CheckMark', if(@currentField == 'Under Review', 'Forward', if(@currentField == 'Need More 
Information', 'Error', if(@currentField == 'More Information Added', 'Error', if(@currentField 
== 'Waiting', 'Warning', if(@currentField == 'Returned', 'ErrorBadge')))))))"
}
    },
    {
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several errors existing in your code:

1. `"background color"` -> `"background-color"`
2. `if(@currentField == 'Returned', '#FA5858')))))))"` -> `if(@currentField == 'Returned', '#FA5858', '#xxxxx')))))))"`
3. `if(@currentField == 'Returned', 'ErrorBadge')))))))"` -> `if(@currentField == 'Returned', 'ErrorBadge', 'xxx')))))))"`

Modify above fields in your code. I achieved what you want by below code.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
   formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField == 'New', '#89CFF0', if(@currentField 
== 'Resolved',  '#A9F5BC', if(@currentField == 'Under Review', '#FFFFFF', 
if(@currentField == 'Need More Information', '#F5DA81', if(@currentField == 
'More Information Added', '#F5DA81', if(@currentField == 'Waiting', '#F79F81', 
if(@currentField == 'Returned', '#FA5858', '#89CFF0')))))))"
  },
 "children": [
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
  "display": "inline-block",
  "padding": "0 4px"
},
 "attributes": {
     "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'New', 'Star', if(@currentField == 
'Resolved', 'CheckMark', if(@currentField == 'Under Review', 'Forward', 
if(@currentField == 'Need More Information', 'Error', if(@currentField == 'More 
Information Added', 'Error', if(@currentField == 'Waiting', 'Warning', 
if(@currentField == 'Returned', 'ErrorBadge', 'CheckMark')))))))"
}
},
  {
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
]
}
```

[image]